# Connected scatterplot missing connecting lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, hrbrthemes

This code is supposed to produce a connected scatterplot ([example found here](https://r-graph-gallery.com/connected_scatterplot_ggplot2.html)), but for some reason there are no connecting lines between the dots when I run the code with my data. What is the reason?

```
library(hrbrthemes)

df_long %>%
  tail(50) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=YEAR, y=value)) +
    geom_line( color="grey") +
    geom_point(shape=21, color="black", fill="#69b3a2", size=6) +
    theme_ipsum() +
    ggtitle("Evolution of prices")
```

Data

```
structure(list(YEAR = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 
18L, 19L, 19L), levels = c("2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", 
"2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021"), class = "factor"), 
    names = c("avg_2", "avg_1", "avg_2", "avg_1", 
    "avg_2", "avg_1", "avg_2", "avg_1", "avg_2", 
    "avg_1", "avg_2", "avg_1", "avg_2", "avg_1", 
    "avg_2", "avg_1", "avg_2", "avg_1", "avg_2", 
    "avg_1", "avg_2", "avg_1", "avg_2", "avg_1", 
    "avg_2", "avg_1", "avg_2", "avg_1", "avg_2", 
    "avg_1", "avg_2", "avg_1", "avg_2", "avg_1", 
    "avg_2", "avg_1", "avg_2", "avg_1"), value = c(9.24465000408397, 
    10.8283582089552, 9.61375824446773, 11.4962264150943, 9.57910257217093, 
    9.97674418604651, 9.55737818803894, 9.93948562783661, 9.66620683746037, 
    9.7574931880109, 10.0840478564307, 10.0276381909548, 11.0876717354968, 
    11.4456824512535, 11.3436795117236, 11.6129476584022, 12.9319600743713, 
    11.7403314917127, 13.4045649811086, 12.5052631578947, 12.5327230426866, 
    12.6259079903148, 13.1406016392921, 12.4209844559585, 12.6763227410025, 
    12.3654114365411, 12.9536953727506, 12.3433734939759, 12.9377914217035, 
    12.4618644067797, 13.6294270858362, 12.3377483443709, 14.5345731090248, 
    13.3298245614035, 14.6696202531646, 14.1116005873715, 16.6562338726815, 
    15.1701030927835)), row.names = c(NA, -38L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: As your `year` column is a `factor` you have to explicitly set the `group` aes to treat all obs. as one group, i.e. try `ggplot( aes(x=YEAR, y=value, group = 1)) + ...`

Comment: ```group``` aes indeed adds lines to the plot, but they connect every dot with each other. In the data there are two data series (```avg_1``` and ```avg_2```) that should not be connected with each other, only with themselves

Comment: Well, then do `group = names`.

Comment: That's how to do it! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You have to mutate `YEAR` as numeric but you have to get the levels, not the values thus `as.numeric(levels(YEAR))[YEAR]` and add in aes `group = names`.

```r
df_long %>%
  tail(50) %>%
  mutate(YEAR = as.numeric(levels(YEAR))[YEAR]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=YEAR, y=value, group = names)) +
  geom_line( color="grey") +
  geom_point(shape=21, color="black", fill="#69b3a2", size=6) +
  theme_ipsum() +
  ggtitle("Evolution of prices")
```

[image]

Comment: your code draws a wrong kind of a plot. As you can see the lines connect every dot with each other. They should connect only the series1 and series2 dots with themselves. ```YEAR``` has to be ```as.factor```

Comment: Okay, now I've understood. I edited the answer so try to check if it's fine for you